# Spring controller isn't receiving HttpServletRequet or @PathVariable or @ModelAttribute values

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, websphere, websphere-7

I have a Spring 4 web app that runs on WebSphere 7 and I can also use Jetty for local development.  I cannot change from WAS and I cannot change the version.  I'm refactoring a very legacy application and attempting to add Spring to handle functionality and I refactor away from servlets.

I have a couple of controllers that work fine in Jetty.  Here are a couple of my request mappings:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/bank/{routingNumber}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public NACHABank getNachaBank(@PathVariable String routingNumber) {
    return bankingService.loadBankByRoutingNumber(routingNumber);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/payment/accountType", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createPaymentBatch(@ModelAttribute PaymentRequest paymentRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
  //do some stuff
  return jspName;
}
```

When I run in WAS (both locally and in my test environments), the `@PathVariable routingNumber` is null.  In the other request mapping the `@ModelAttribute paymentRequest` and `HttpServletRequest request` are null.

When I run in Jetty, they are not and everything works.

In WAS, I have no errors in server startup and I get the normal Spring startup messages.  My endpoints are mapped ie:

`[6/28/16 10:20:30:695 CDT] 00000025 RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register Mapped "{[/bank/{routingNumber}],methods=[GET]}" onto public com.company.domain.NACHABank com.company.view.controller.BankController.getNachaBank(java.lang.String)`

`[6/28/16 10:20:30:726 CDT] 00000025 RequestMappin I org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping register Mapped "{[/payment/paymentType],methods=[POST]}" onto public java.lang.String com.company.view.controller.PaymentController.createPaymentBatch(com.company.view.request.PaymentRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)`

What could be causing this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I walked back through my commit history, I knew this worked at one point.  A few months ago I upgraded to Spring 4.3 from 4.1.1, and that's what caused the controllers to break.  I downgraded to 4.1.1 and everything works now.

Comment: Actually, under some circumtances, all you need is just to "Clean & Build" you project, upgrading shouldn't be problem, downgrading is..., btw +1 for providing an answer.

Comment: You're welcome.  A `mvn clean install` was not sufficient in this case.  For an unknown reason Spring 4.3 would not work.  My test environments were given a new ear file built in a clean workspace from Jenkins.  This is an old code base that still relies on TopLink and some other ancient libraries my company forced all projects to use back in the day.  I did a UI facelift but couldn't remove all the crap and migrate to Tomcat for this project.